# Number of samples needed before sample maximum greater than some value

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

Let's say you have a standard normal distribution, and you are sampling from this $N$ times. How many samples will it take before the maximum observed value will be at least 3 (or in general some value $K$)?

To solve this problem I considered the CDF of the normal distribution for when $x >= 3 $. This gives that the probability of finding a value of $x >= 3$ in one sample is $0.0013499$. Since we know all our samples are independent of each other, the answer would appear to be the mean of the geometric distribution that results with $p=0.0013499$, which is $740.97$.

However, by simulating a large number of trials I found that the true answer is around 444 trials. (Here's the mathematica code to show this `Table[Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {x, 1, 444}] // 
   Max, {k, 1, 1000}] // Mean`

This can also be verified mathematically by solving the reverse problem: the expected sample maximum from $N$ trials. Note that $[Pr(x <= K)]^{444}$ — the probability that the results from all 444 trials are less than k — constitutes a CDF for all 444 trials. From this the corresponding PDF (albeit in terms of Erf function) can be found by differentiating, and finding the expected value of this PDF (or letting mathematica approximate the integral numerically) indeed gives that 444 trials is sufficient to have an expected sample maximum of 3.

So why did my attempt to solve the problem overshoot the answer?

Comment: Are you sure of your simulations ? When I try it, I find a result very close to the theoretical one of 1/p.

Comment: @jlesuffleur I added Mathematica code to the post above

Comment: The mean number of samples necessary before one value exceeds 3 is around 741. You have drawn samples and the sample number 444 exceeded 3. Where is the contradiction? If you repeat the experiment, you should get various numbers of samples and the mean of these numbers should close in to 741.

Comment: @Did I did repeat the experiment (hence the `{k, 1, 1000}] // Mean` part that repeats 1000 times the experiment of drawing 444 samples and finding the maximum then averages those maximums to arrive at a good estimate of the expected value of the sample maximum from 444 trials.

Comment: Then there is a phenomenon at work here. See a proposition of explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your post correctly (but beware that I checked none of the numerical values involved), you are successively solving two different problems.

In both cases, one is given a sequence $(X_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ i.i.d. standard normal and one considers its running maximum defined for every $n\geqslant1$ as $M_n=\max\{X_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$.

**Approach "741":** Let $\theta_3=E(T_3)$ where $T_3=\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid X_n\geqslant3\}$, then $\theta_3=P(X_1\geqslant3)^{-1}$ and you say that $\theta_3\approx741$.

**Approach "444":** Let $\mu_3=\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid E(M_n)\geqslant3\}$, then you say that $\mu_3\approx444$.

Since $T_3$ is also $T_3=\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid M_n\geqslant3\}$, one is considering either
$$E(\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid M_n\geqslant3\})$$ or $$\inf\{n\geqslant1\mid E(M_n)\geqslant3\}$$ which need not coincide.

Answer (score 0):

For given $p=Q(3)$ value $E[T]=1\times p+ (1+E[T])\times (1-p)=740.7967$ (approximately) as you have indicated,
Simply your simulation must be incorrect, here is my very layman piece of Matlab code

```
N=100000;
res=zeros(1,N);
parfor (ii=1:N)
k=1; 
while(randn(1,1)<=3)
k=k+1;
end
res(ii)=k;
end
mean(res)
```

For my sample run it gave 742.5393

Comment: Interesting. The only possible thing I could find is that your simulation draws samples one at a time checking if the last sample you drew is greater than 3 and drawing another if not. Whereas my simulation blindly generates 400 samples, then measures its maximum. I think my situation doesn't fit a geometric distribution since you do a fixed number of trials one-shot then measure the maximum.